# How do I print the {{messages}} variable?

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 7 I was able to do something like this:

```
<?php echo $messages; ?>
```

It seems this variable is no more in Drupal 8.

```
{{messages}} // This returns NULL on {{dump(messages)}}.
```

I basically have a page--user--login.html.twig where I output the page.content and above that I want the messages to be displayed, in case there are errors on the page and not the entire header.

```
// Not desirable
{% if page.header %}
   {% block header %}
     <div class="col-sm-12" role="heading">
         {{ page.header }}
      </div>
   {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

What is the correct variable name for `<?php echo $messages ?>` in Drupal 8?

Comment: Status Messages is a block now, it'll appear in whatever region you place it in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default the messages are in the highlighted region, put this in your page twig:

```
{{ page.highlighted }}
```

If you changed the block layout, go to

```
admin/structure/block
```

and check in which region you placed the status message block. When it is disabled, move it back into a region.

Comment: It seems mine was in another region and I placed it back into the highlighted region it's the only one there so it prints nicely. Is there a way to print out a certain block from a region rather than printing out the entire region? i.e {{ page.header.status-message }}

Answer (score 1):

I display block with status messages by the next way:

1. in hook_preprocess_page() add custom variable and put in messages block

`function my_theme_preprocess_page(array &$variables) {
    // add messages block to front page
    if ($variables['is_front']) {
        $block_msg = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('dtt_theme_messages');
        $variables['custom_system_messages'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getViewBuilder('block')
        -    >view($block_msg);
    }
}`

2. in twig template, for my example page--front.html.twig, I can insert block with messages in any place

`{{ custom_system_messages }}`

Answer (score 1):

you can print the message by:

```
{{ page.highlighted.bartik_messages }}
```

bartik_messages is the Machine name of this block for current theme[image]

In general, you could use the following pattern:

```
{{ page.MESSAGES_BLOCK_REGION.THEME_NAME_messages }}
```